# Winapi children of MFC window

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

It is a simple question that I might delete soon, but I have a problem that I don't seem to find anywhere else (at least google has not helped).

I am trying to write a plugin for a software based completely in MFC, but I refuse to use MFC myself. I thought that, in the end, I could just use the proper handles and modules to create my windows with winapi to work with MFC but it does not seem that easy. I am trying to launch a "Modal" window (that is, it blocks the parent by calling `EnableWindow(parentHwnd, FALSE)`). For this window I wrote a custom wndProc function:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK wndProc(HWND hwnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    //Do stuff to get a HWND to the parent window
    switch(msg) {
        case WM_CLOSE:
            EnableWindow(parentHwnd, TRUE);
            //DestroyWindow(hwnd);
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
        case WM_DESTROY:
            EnableWindow(parentHwnd, TRUE);
            //PostQuitMessage(0);
            return DefWindowProc(hwnd, msg, wParam, lParam);
    //... Handling other messages
```

When the user closes the window, I want to enable the parent and simply close my custom window. You can see that the functions `DestroyWindow(hwnd)` and `PostQuitMessage(0)` are commented, and instead I return `DefWindowProc`. This is because leaving the message uncommented, the whole app crashes with the following exception:

[image]

My first guess would be that there is a problem with the messages in windows. I don't know if I am forced to use the "DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP" macro or something to handle my events in MFC's wndProc. I'm quite a beginner for windows development so, even though I found a solution for this crash, I'm not quite satisfied because I have no idea why it failed in the first place. Thank you!

Comment: You shouldn't call `PostQuitMessage()` unless you _actually_ want to quit the application. Have you tried it with just that commented out? Leave the `DestroyWindow()` enabled.

Comment: You shouldn't have any problems embedding normal C- or C++-implemented windows in an MFC application. Standard buttons, etc., work, and they're written in plain-ol' C.

Comment: Hard to tell, what the issue is, without any information to go by. How is your plugin loaded? Does it run on a different thread from the owner window? Have you enabled the option to break into the debugger, when an exception is thrown (look at the code in the error message to figure out, which type of exception to listen for). After you've done that, what is the improper argument? At any rate, mixing MFC with Windows API windows is not an issue. MFC is just a C++(-ish) wrapper around the Windows API.

Comment: It must be a dll, it runs on the same thread as the owner window. I'll launch the debugger to find out what the kind of exception is and I'll update. Thank you for the suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

First, what is a "plugin" exactly? From what I can guess it must be just some additional code, built into the main executable (otherwise you wouldn't be asking about message-maps and that "MFC's wndProc"). As for your question, maybe you don't really need to get into this. I'm just wondering if it would work just calling:

`DialogBox(AfxGetInstanceHandle(), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_MYDIALOG), parentHwnd, MyDlgProc);`

Comment: It must be a dll because it calls DllMain somewhere (even though the file has a custom file extension). At the beginning I even had problems getting the proper module to load resources, but after messing a bit with the `afx` methods I made it work. It feels like the messages are just not arriving to the correct WndProc callback function.

Comment: Well, if you have that `parentHwnd` available in your plugin (whatever it is), it wouldn't be hard to first create a modal dialog-box as a test. Create it in the same thread that owns `parentHwnd`. Resources are simply loaded from the module they are contained into. And DllMain isn't called by the app, but indirectly by the system, on load/unload/thread attach/detach events. But still, not knowing what the plugin actually is doesn't help other members provide you any assistance. It's easy to tell, just check the project type you build. And is it the same module as the MFC-implemented one?